# Create a configuration with symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to create this configuration on Symfony

```
media:
    medias:
        category.type.subtype:
            reference : "UUID" # What is used to identify object in DB (needed)
            service : ~ # Service name "bundle.service.name"

            identifiers: # If empty, no generator can be created for this media
                channelId: # Example
                    label: ~ # Label for front
                    key: "channel_id" # Identifier in bdd (default : the name of identifier)
                channelTitle: ~
                # Other identifier....

            api: # Api configuration (can be null if no API)
                consumer_key: ~
                consumer_secret: ~
                # Others parameters...

            parameters:
                label: "Media 1" # Label in the front Default : generated with the name
                page:
                    factor: 50 # Factor (default 20)
                    styles:
                        style1:
                            css_class: class1
                        style2:
                            css_class: class2
                        # Other styles...
        category.type.subtype2: #parameters.....
```

I've written this code :

```
    $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('media');

    $rootNode
        ->children()
            ->arrayNode("medias")
                ->prototype('array')
                    ->children()
                        ->scalarNode('reference')
                            ->isRequired()
                        ->end()

                        ->scalarNode('service')->end()

                        ->arrayNode("identifiers")
                            ->prototype('array')
                                ->children()
                                    ->scalarNode("label")->end()
                                    ->scalarNode("key")->end()
                                ->end()
                            ->end()
                        ->end()

                        ->arrayNode("api")
                            ->prototype('scalar')->end()
                        ->end()

                        ->arrayNode("parameters")
                            ->scalarNode("label")->end()

                            ->arrayNode("page")
                                ->children()
                                    ->integerNode("factor")->end()

                                    ->arrayNode("styles")
                                        ->prototype('array')
                                            ->children()
                                                ->scalarNode("css_class")->end()
                                            ->end()
                                        ->end()
                                    ->end()

                                ->end()
                            ->end()

                        ->end()

                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ;
```

But I've the error :

> Call to undefined method Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\ArrayNodeDefinition::scalarNode()

And I've absolutly no idea where this error come from :/

Comment: Which line is the issue? You've removed that information from the error.

Comment: The CLI doesn't indicate me the line :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specified which line of code is the issue, but for me it looks like you forgot to call `children()` method after `parameters` node definition:

```
->arrayNode("parameters")
    ->scalarNode("label")->end()
```

It should be something like:

```
->arrayNode("parameters")
    ->children()
        ->scalarNode("label")->end()
        // other nodes
    ->end()
```